# How can I change the scale of a 3D Object and the Audio Source's radius in a proportionally way in Unity 5 using C#?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I'm using an Array to multiply a 3D object randomly in the space, so i'm getting a lot of nice objects floating randomly over the y, x and z axes. 
This object has also an Audio Source with a sound attached to it, which means that after applying the random-array-positioning I get different objects with different Audio Sources as well.

The problem is that I'm also changing the scale of those objects, which it's working super well, but the size/scale/radius of the Audio Source it's not changing at all.

How can I change the scale of the objects and change the size/scale/radius of the Audio Source at the same time, to match both equally or proportionally in size?

I'm looking here but I Can't figured out.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html

This is the code that I'm using for:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class multipleObjectsGrandes : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject prefabGrandes;

public GameObject[] gos;
public int cantidad;
public float minScaleObj;
public float maxScaleObj;


void Awake()
{
    gos = new GameObject[cantidad];
    for(int i = 0; i < gos.Length; i++)
    {

        //Position
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-40.0f, 40.0f), Random.Range(-40.0f, 40.0f), Random.Range(-40.0f, 40.0f));
        GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabGrandes, position, Quaternion.identity);

        //Scale
        clone.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * Random.Range(minScaleObj, maxScaleObj);

        //Rotation
        clone.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f));

        gos[i] = clone;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the [maxDistance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-maxDistance.html) value? You'd have to use `gameObject.getComponent<AudioSource>()` to get a reference to the audio source and then multiply the relevant field.

Comment: Thanks @Draco18s. 
Now i'm trying to pass the reference from the scale on this script (transform.localScale) to the maxDistance variable, which is attached to the audioSource game object. 

The problem is that I'm always getting the same number, it's like the it's reading only the first instance and the taking the same value again and again :/

Comment: Can you edit your question with your current code?

Comment: @Draco18s Sure! see below!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that i'm using to multiply objects:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class multipleObjectsGrandes : MonoBehaviour
    {

    public GameObject prefabGrandes;

    public GameObject[] cuerpos;
    public int cantidad;
    public float minScaleObj;
    public float maxScaleObj;

    public float escalaMax;

    void Awake ()
    {
        cuerpos = new GameObject[cantidad];
        for (int i = 0; i < cuerpos.Length; i++) {

            //Position
            Vector3 position = new Vector3 (Random.Range (-40.0f, 40.0f), Random.Range (-40.0f, 40.0f), Random.Range (-40.0f, 40.0f));

            GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate (prefabGrandes, position, Quaternion.identity);

            //Scale
            clone.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * Random.Range (minScaleObj, maxScaleObj);

            //Rotation
            clone.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (Random.Range (0.0f, 360.0f), Random.Range (0.0f, 360.0f), Random.Range (0.0f, 360.0f));

            escalaMax = clone.transform.localScale.x;

            //Debug.Log(escalaMax);

            }
        }
    }
```

Everything is ok here when I'm debugging "escalaMax" in the console.

The variable "escalaMax" is the one that i'm passing to the other script which is inside the object that I'm multiplying which has an audioSource attached to it. This is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent (typeof(AudioSource))]

public class AudioRandomPitch : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float startingPitch = 1;
    public float minPitchRandom = 0;
    public float maxPitchRandom = 0;
    AudioSource audio;

    public float audioScale;

    void Start ()
    {
        startingPitch = Random.Range (minPitchRandom, maxPitchRandom);
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        audio.pitch = startingPitch;

        GameObject theMultiplicator = GameObject.Find ("Multiplicador_deCuerpos");
        multipleObjectsGrandes multiplicatorScript = theMultiplicator.GetComponent<multipleObjectsGrandes> ();
        multiplicatorScript.escalaMax = audioScale;

        //this is not working
        audio.maxDistance = audioScale;

        Debug.Log(audioScale);



    }
}
```

Here I'm first saving the value coming from the other script escalaMax inside the new variable audioScale. 
The problem now is when I try to pass the audioScale value to the audio.maxDistance var.

I'm super close I know, but as you can see, i'm not a really good programmer and I'm probably doing something stupidly wrong... :/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1) You shouldn't post updated code as an answer (it's not an answer, its still the question). 2) You'd be better off doing `clone.getComponent<AudioRandomPitch>().audioScale = escalaMax`